# Grid whose amount of columns should be between 1 and 3

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

On my website I have a grid which should have between 1 and 3 columns. I can easily make the amount of columns dynamic by using `auto-fit`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min-content, 1fr));
  gap: 40px;
}
```

However the amount of columns can go above 3 which looks terrible on wider screens and I couldn't find a way to limit the amount of columns.
This is what it looks like with 5 columns (bad):
[image: bad image]

I tried using `max(3)` instead of`auto-fit`, but that just set the amount to 3, not making it dynamic.
What's something I can do to limit the amount of columns to 3?

Comment: Nope that's not the way Css-grid works.

Comment: @Paulie_D What do you mean?

Comment: You can chose between a set number of columns or let the browser decide. You can't have a range of columns.

Comment: @Paulie_D Alright, what can I do about it?

Comment: Nothing really.

Comment: @Paulie_D U serious. There sure has to be a way. Possibly not with CSS, but there has to be. Saying I can't do anything ruins the purpose of asking

Comment: Use media queries to adjust the number of columns by screen size.

Comment: Try this, adjusted to your needs repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it like this:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  gap: 40px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1450px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(300px, 1fr));
  }
}
```

Thanks for the `@media` suggestion!